# Skikit Learn multiple regression models

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn

Is it possible to use different models for different features, e.g. when i want to predict housing prices from median income, I would use an linear model but when i want to predict them from coordinates it would be better to use k-nearest-Neighbors.

```
import sklearn
import numpy as np

X_housing_income = np.array([l[0] for l in X_housing].reshape(-1,1)
X_housing_latitude = np.array([l[1] for l in X_housing].reshape(-1,1)
X_housing_longitude = np.array([l[2] for l in X_housing].reshape(-1,1)

lin_reg_income = sklearn.linear_model.LinearRegression()
lin_reg_income.fit(X_housing_income,y_housing)

knn_reg_latitude = sklearn.neighbors.KNeighborsRegression()
knn_reg_latitude.fit(X_housing_latitude,y_housing)

knn_reg_longitude = sklearn.neighbors.KNeighborsRegression()
knn_reg_longitude.fit(X_housing_longitude,y_housing)

prediction_income = lin_reg_income.predict(some_income)
prediction_latitude = knn_reg_latitude.predict(some_latitude)
prediction_longitude = knn_reg_longitude.predict(some_longitude)

prediction_mean = (prediction_income + prediction_latitude + prediction_longitude) / 2
```

Is there a way to combine this in scikit-learn or is it better to implement it by myself?

Comment: I suggest you to review your question providing your programming efforts to solve your problem or, alternatively, to move to: https://stats.stackexchange.com/

Comment: disagree with @ScipioneSarlo, stats.stackexchange tends to focus on "hand calculations" or theory.  This question doesn't really belong anywhere.

Comment: But to answer the original question, you'll have to train different models using your desired input data. It's possible to write up code using pandas that does a "for this sample, drop all NaN, and pick a model"  but sklearn doesn't have that feature

Comment: @MohammadAthar, I suggested it because CrossValidated is "for statisticians, data miners, and anyone else doing data analysis or interested in it as a discipline. If you have a question about

statistical analysis, applied or theoretical
designing experiments
collecting data
data mining
machine learning
visualizing data
probability theory
mathematical statistics
statistical and data-driven computing" and it seems that pgmcr is asking for a methodological support

Answer (score 0):

You'll have to do this yourself, but check out this writeup I did on working with missing data- https://colab.research.google.com/drive/1ZyyppDx72d6bRZc2q4ksqrmHsXHvkGI6

In it, near the end, I create a class designed to use pandas to detect which entries in a given sample are NaN (just set house price to NaN every time), and then select an appropriate set of models.

Currently, it only chooses a small ANN as a model (but you can change that pretty easily) and the averaging technique needs to be tweaked, but it should get you started on the right path

Answer (score 0):

I just implemented it by myself beacause it seems like there is nothing like this in scikit-learn:

```
class MultiModelRegressor(RegressorMixin):
    def __init__(self,models):
        self.models = models
    def fit(self, X, y):
        X_ = X.copy().reshape(X.shape[1], X.shape[0])
        y_ = y.copy().reshape(-1, y.shape[0])
        for features, labels, model in [(a,b,c) for a in X_ for b in y_ for c in self.models]:
            if not model == None:
                model.fit(features.reshape(-1,1), labels.reshape(-1,1))
    def predict(self, X):
        X_ = X.copy().reshape(X.shape[1], X.shape[0])
        prediction = np.empty(X.shape[0])
        for features, model in [(a,b) for a in X_ for b in self.models]:
            if not model == None:
                prediction = (np.array([a+b for a in prediction for b in model.predict(features.reshape(-1,1))] ) / 2)
        return prediction.reshape(X.shape[0])
```

its not perfect, but i cant really undestand why something like this isnt already in scikit learn, i mean its pretty useful isn't it?

Comment: This can be done with a combination of FeatureUnion and Pipeline.

Comment: @Vivek Kumar could you please show me how to do it?